Energy of a solution to the heat equation on the unit square goes to zero

Let $w(x,y,t)$ solve the diffusion equation $w_t = w_{xx} + w_{yy}$ on the unit square $0 \le x, y \le 1$, with $w(\xi, \eta, t) =0$ for all $(\xi, \eta)$ on the boundary of the square and $t \ge 0$. Define the energy
$$\phi(t) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 w^2 \, \mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy.$$
It is easy (and standard) to show that $\phi'(t) \le 0$. Show that $\phi(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

This feels like a standard result, but I've struggled to find satisfactory elementary proofs. Intuitively, this makes sense – the diffusion is smoothing and tends to the 'steady state' $w \equiv 0$. Note that since $\phi'(t) \le 0$ and $\phi(t) \ge 0$, $\phi(t) \to L$ as $t \to \infty$ where $L \ge 0$. It remains to show that $L = 0$.
One possible proof given to me runs as follows (assuming suitably nice conditions on $w$ – I'm not too worried about this).

Observe that for $0 \le \alpha \le 1$, \begin{align*}
w(\alpha, y, t)^2 &= \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d \alpha} \int_0^\alpha w(x,y,t) \, \mathrm dx \right)^2 = \left(\int_0^\alpha w_x(x,y,t) \, \mathrm dx \right)^2 \\
&\le \int_0^\alpha w_x(x,y,t)^2 \, \mathrm dx \le \int_0^1 w_x(x,y,t)^2 \, \mathrm dx,
\end{align*}
by the fundamental theorem of calculus (with $w(0,y,t) = 0$), differentiation under the integral sign and the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality. Similarly, $w(x, \beta, t)^2 \le \int_0^1 w_y(x,y,t)^2 \, \mathrm dt$.
Since $\phi(t) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 w^2 \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy$ and $\phi'(t) = -2 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (w_x^2 + w_y^2) \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy$ (easy to show), \begin{align*}
2 \phi(t) &= 2 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 w(\alpha, \beta, t)^2 \, \mathrm d \alpha \, \mathrm d \beta \\ &\le \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 w_x(x, \beta, t)^2 \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm d\alpha \, \mathrm d \beta + \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 w_y(\alpha, y, t)^2 \, \mathrm dy \, \mathrm d\alpha \, \mathrm d \beta \\ &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (w_x^2 + w_y^2) \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy = -\frac 12 \phi'(t).
\end{align*}
Thus, $\phi'(t) = -4 \phi(t) \implies  \phi(t) \sim e^{-4t} \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

Fine. Two questions:

Does this proof work? I think it does, but it feels pulled from nowhere and I would have struggled to come up with this myself. (I use the solution-verification tag while not identifying a particular step with some trepidation).
Is there a more general result in the literature? The fact that the energy associated to the solution of the heat equation goes to zero in this case seems pretty important. What if we aren't on the unit square? What if the boundary values are not zero?

Source: this question was inspired by question 8 on the first example sheet for the Numerical Analysis course in Part II of the Mathematical Tripos at the University of Cambridge.

This very old unanswered question is related, but on $(0,1) \times (0,\infty)$ and with different boundary conditions.

On a finite domain in euclidean $\mathbb R^n$ with reasonable picewise continuous boundary and integrable boundary conditons, the Laplacian is a negative semidefinite operator with discrete spectrum.
The harmonic function $f_0(x)$ with maximal eigenvalue zero is uniquely determined by the integral over the boundary with the Cauchy kernel.
All other eigenfunctions $f_k(x)$ with zero boundary conditons  have negative eigenvalues $\lambda_k < 0, k\in \mathbb N_+$.
It follows that the solution of the heat/diffusion  equations have the form
$$f(t,x) = f_0(x) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{\lambda_k t} f_k(x)  $$
The $\mathit L_2$ norm converges to the norm of the harmonic ground state with rate given be the highest negative nonzero eigenvalue $e^{2\lambda_1 t}$ because the eigenfunctions are orthogonal.
The trivial exponential dying in time of the non-harmonic Fourier components is hard to show in the position space representation.

Thanks for this. Can you see any way in which this relates to the proof I gave in my answer? In particular I can see some $L^2$-esque norms floating around; is my proof a simple case/restatement of this result?
